# Power BI Dax Calculate days MAX date and second date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to get the "Lag" days between the MAX "Physical date" and "terms approved date." This is the code I am currently using but it is not working:

```
Lag = DATEDIFF(CALCULATE(MAX(cr93f_cpsoo[Physical Date]), cr93f_cpsoo[Terms Approved DateTime]),DAY())
```

Error: Too few arguments were passed to the DAY function. The minimum argument count for the function is 1.

I tried:

```
Lag = DATEDIFF(CALCULATE(MAX(cr93f_cpsoo[Physical Date]), cr93f_cpsoo[Terms Approved DateTime]),DAY())
```

Error: Too few arguments were passed to the DAY function. The minimum argument count for the function is 1.

Comment: The third argument of a [`DATEDIFF`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/datediff-function-dax) in an Interval, in your case it is just `DAY` and not the function [`DAY()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/day-function-dax).